# How to set the window decorator color on an Android app in Chromebook?

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

There are many "default" apps that have the window decorator matching the app color theme such as the Youtube or Google Play apps.

My app otherwise has a gray bar (the bottom one in the pic) as most of the apps one can download from Google Play that aren't from Google. 
How can I change the color of it?

[image: Window Decorator color comparison]

Answer (score 0):

The window decoration color roughly follows the status bar color. You can set it at runtime via [Window#setStatusBarColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int))

If you do not set it specifically, the color will be derived from your [theme colors](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html).

So setting ColorPrimaryDark or ColorPrimary would define your decorations color.

The color can't be transparent, if it is, you might get the grey color you are seeing.

If you are still not seeing the right color, you are hitting a bug that should be fixed in ChromeOS 60.